# Does pseudo-holomorphic *submanifolds* satisfy unique continuation?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sg.symplectic-geometry, elliptic-pde

Let $f,g:(D^2,j_\mathrm{std})\to(B^{2n}(1),J)$ be two pseudo-holomorphic maps.  The following unique continuation result is well-known (it may be proved using either Aronszajn's Lemma or the Carleman similarity principle as in Floer--Hofer--Salamon):

**Lemma:** Suppose $f=g$ over a neighborhood of $0\in D^2$.  Then $f=g$ everywhere.

Is there a similar unique continuation result for pseudo-holomorphic *submanifolds* (instead of *maps*)?  Here is a precise formulation of what I expect might be true:

**Conjecture**: Let $U,V\subseteq(D^2)^\circ$ be two closed topological disks with smooth boundary, and let $\phi:U^\circ\to V^\circ$ be a biholomorphism (which necessarily extends continuously to a homeomorphism $U\to V$).  Suppose $f=g\circ\phi$ over $U$.  Then $\phi$ extends holomorphically to an open neighborhood of $U$ (and hence $f=g\circ\phi$ over this neighborhood by the unique continuation result for maps).

Is some statement along these lines known?

Comment: It looks like Theorem 2.83 in Chris Wendl's book http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1690v2 might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: It seems that you have found the answer, but I thought of a simpler approach (maybe wrong): what about the subset of $D^2\times D^2$ defined by $g(x)=f(y)$ ? It should be complex analytic (for the standard complex structure), and your assumption amounts to say that it contains the graph of your $\phi:U\to V$. Maybe the assumption of smoothness of boundaries of $U,V$ and local structure of complex analytic curves would suffice to conclude ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The desired statement is in fact a well known property of pseudo-holomorphic maps.  Lemma 1.3.1 in [Singularities and positivity of
intersections of J-holomorphic curves](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1274930) by Dusa McDuff says that for a pair of pseudo-holomorphic maps $u,v:(D^2,0)\to(M,p)$ with $du(0)\ne 0$, either $u(0)=v(0)$ is an isolated point of intersection, or $v$ factors through $u$.  This (combined with, say the fact that critical points of pseudo-holomorphic maps are isolated, see Lemma 1.2.1 in the same paper) gives the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer is yes.

Given that the domain has a real analytic boundary the construction is standard. A Schwarz reflection can be performed locally near each boundary point, which together with normal analytic continuation produces the sought extension.

In general, I propose the following approach. Assume that $f(D^2) \subset g(D^2)$. The critical points of $g$ (and $f$) form a discrete set by the aforementioned similarity principle. Away from the critical points $\phi^{-1}(\mathrm{Crit}(g))$, we can write $\phi=g^{-1} \circ f$ and in this way obtain a unique continuation along small punctured discs covering the boundary of $U$. However, since $\phi$ is bounded along the boundary by assumption, the removal of singularities theorem can be applied to complete $\phi$ over the punctures.

**Remark.** At least in real dimension four, the assumption $f(D^2) \subset g(D^2)$ is not too severe since two unparametrised pseudo-holomorphic curves intersect in a *discrete* set, as was show in [[McDuff; The Local Behaviour of J-holomorphic Curves in Almost Complex 4-manifolds]](https://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjIqe_S1d3HAhXiD3IKHYaEAIk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Feuclid.jdg%2F1214446994&usg=AFQjCNFt-m8b1Y8S5ByNlkcYGliYj-cMIQ&sig2=zsERC9XMhA0bzk1PV_IySQ&bvm=bv.101800829,d.bGQ).

(As a particular case, which however is no longer relevant given the new general formulation of the question: Every biholomorphism $\phi$ of $D^2(r)^o \subset \mathbb{C}$ which has a continuous extension to $D^2(r)$ extends to a *biholomorphism* of the *Riemann sphere*. Here we use a Schwarz reflection along $\partial D^2(r)$.)

Comment: Indeed, the question was sort of trivial as I originally phrased it.  I've now modified it to be nontrivial.

Comment: I agree. Hopefully the new answer gives the complete picture for your question. For the applications, I would imagine that you can get away by assuming a real analytic boundary (cover your Riemann surface with small analytic discs). But OK, here I'm just guessing what applications you have in mind.

Comment: Why is the answer no in general?  I think you are missing the hypothesis that $f=g\circ\phi$ (which is really the crux of the question).

Comment: Of course, you are right. Let me try to fix it by applying the application I had in mind, hopefully it will work...

Comment: I don't understand.  As you remarked before, the answer is clearly "no" if we omit the hypothesis $f=g\circ\phi$.  Now you claim the answer is "yes", but your argument does not use the fact that $f=g\circ\phi$.  Note that $\phi$ need not send your disks with analytic boundary to other disks with analytic boundary.

Comment: Sorry, my previous approach was clearly incorrect. Is my new proposal general enough for you?